# Best development environment for PHP?

Tags: php, windows, development-environment

What is the best development environment for PHP?
I use Notepad++ with Vibrant Ink style and Windows Explorer for ftp.

very amateurish

Comment: Servers are often powered by Linux, the best development machine wouldn't be a Windoze one...

Comment: @Lekensteyn - Servers may be powered by Linux, but saying that Windows machines are not good dev machines is pure flamebait.

Comment: What has a server got to do with a development machine in that context? Even if you're referring to installing server software on a development machine, is server software so different on either OS anyway?

Comment: PHP on windows has a few quirks relative to linux, but it doesn't add up to much. It's a cross platform, interpreted language after all, so it should run the same regardless of your OS. My impression from seeing various questions is that it's a little more difficult to set up on Windows and sometimes there is some confusing stuff about file paths, or a few more bugs than the linux versions. But if you're not even running Apache/PHP on the development machine it makes no difference at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Ubuntu on my development desktop, running Apache with the same setup on the server on which the code is deployed.  Not having to upload code to a remote server to run it is really convenient! It made my workflow a lot more graceful when I started doing this. Just save the file and hit f5, and your changes are there instantly.

[Kate](http://kate-editor.org/) is my favorite editor for Linux. Notepadd++ and Kate are similar, but I consider Kate to be better organized.  I don't think Kate is available for Windows, though.

Another editor I like is [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) (that page is confusing, though - the editor *is* free, but they offer a commercial IDE as well). The handiest feature about Komodo, for me, is you can transparently edit remote files via ssh, so you don't need to worry about uploading or anything.

Does Windows Explorer support sftp? Using the plain FTP protocol isn't recommended, as it sends your authentication details (and all transfers) unencrypted. You may wish to get a program such as [filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) and start using sftp.

I wrote a small wrapper for [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) so I can just upload files from the console, like `ssend newfile.php`.  It's pretty convenient for when you're just editing a couple of files.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is really subjective. You can check out [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) and [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/org/foundation/), but not sure what's wrong with Notepad++ :(

Edit: Oh, [RapidPHP](http://www.blumentals.net/rapidphp/index.php), friend of my swears by that.

Answer (score 1):

Dupe of quite a few questions here.  Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap

I use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) by the way.